# Finding First Appearing Value in a List of Duplicate Values

Tags: mysql

I have a table that stores the statuses an applications goes through. Some applications go through the same status multiple times. Each time it goes through a status, the time of the status change is recorded.

How can I pull a list of applications based on the first time applications goes through a particular status within a specified date range. Below is what I have tried thus far:

```
SELECT d1.STATUS,
d1.APPL_ID
FROM APP_STATUS d1
LEFT JOIN APP_STATUS d2 ON d1.APPL_ID = d2.APPL_ID AND d1.STATUS = 'AT_CUSTOMER' AND d2.STATUS = 'AT_CUSTOMER'
    WHERE DATE(d1.STATUS_CREATE_DT) >= '2014-10-26'
    AND DATE(d1.STATUS_CREATE_DT) <= '2014-11-25'
    AND d2.STATUS IS NULL
        GROUP BY d1.APPL_ID;
```

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0):

To get the first time a status goes through, try this query:

```
select a.appl_id, min(status_create_dt) as first_dt
from ap_status
where d.STATUS_CREATE_DT >= '2014-10-26' and
      d.STATUS_CREATE_DT < date('2014-11-25') + interval 1 day and
      d2.STATUS IS NULL
group by a.appl_id;
```

I think this does what you need.  If you want more columns, then you can join this back to `ap_status`.

Note that I changed the date logic a bit.  The date functions are only on the constant side of the dates.  This allows the query to take advantage of an index on `STATUS_CREATE_DT`, if appropriate.